# In keeping with the recent questions on closures used to pass data between VCs, how would I do the same when using a containerVC within the rootVC?

Tags: swift

I saw a recent bountied question (can find the link if you wish to see it) about using closures to pass data between VCs where one VC was embedded in a navigation controller. While the use of a closure there was fairly easy since there was a direct point of contact between the two VCs (in the form a segue), I have been wondering how the same would work if this was not the case.

As an example, consider the following set up (similar to the OG question that inspired this post):

**RootVC, which has a counter UILabel**

**A subContainer VC which takes up the lower half of RootVC, which has a button, pressing which should increment the UILabel on RootVC by one.**

I have prepared the code as follows (with some code taken from the OG question):

**RootVC:**

```
class RootVC: UIViewController {

    var tappedCount: Int = 0

    let pagingContainer: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "\(tappedCount)"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Copperplate", size: 90)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(label)
        view.addSubview(pagingContainer)

        pagingContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        pagingContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        pagingContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        pagingContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = true

        let pageController = PageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
               addChild(pageController)
               pageController.didMove(toParent: self)
               pageController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
               pagingContainer.addSubview(pageController.view)

               pageController.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pagingContainer.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
               pageController.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pagingContainer.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true

               pageController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pagingContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
               pageController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pagingContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
               pageController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pagingContainer.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
               pageController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pagingContainer.trailingAnchor).isActive = true


        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true


 label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: pagingContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true     
          }
       }
```

**SubContainerVC:**

```
class SubContainerVC: UIViewController {

    var callback : (() -> Void)?

    let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Button!", for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = .green
        return button
    }()

    @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Hello")
        //Pressing this button should increment the label on RootVC by one.
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        view.addSubview(button)

        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}
```

**And the PageViewController swift file:**

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {

    lazy var subViewControllers:[UIViewController] = {
        return [SubContainerVC()]
    }()


    init(transitionStyle style:
        UIPageViewController.TransitionStyle, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewController.NavigationOrientation, options: [String : Any]? = nil) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    }



    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        dataSource = self
        delegate = self
        setViewControllerFromIndex(index: 0)
    }

    func setViewControllerFromIndex(index:Int) {
        self.setViewControllers([subViewControllers[index]], direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return subViewControllers.count
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex:Int = subViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) ?? 0
        if currentIndex <= 0 {
            return nil
        }
        return subViewControllers[currentIndex-1]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex:Int = subViewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) ?? 0
        if currentIndex >= subViewControllers.count-1 {
            return nil
        }
        return subViewControllers[currentIndex+1]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the closure downstream to `SubContainerVC`, this will result in the closure execution coming up upstream.

Something along the lines (kept only the relevant VC code):

```swift
class SubContainerVC {
    var buttonCallback: () -> Void = { }

    @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Hello")
        buttonCallback()
    }
}

class PageViewController: UIViewController {

    // Note that you don't need the extra closure call for lazy vars 
    lazy var subViewControllers = [SubContainerVC()] {
        didSet {
            // just in case the controllers might change later on
            subViewControllers.forEach { $0.buttonCallback = buttonCallback }
        }
    }

    var buttonCallback: () -> Void = { } {
        didSet { 
            subViewControllers.forEach { $0.buttonCallback = buttonCallback }
        }
    }
}

class RootVC: UIViewController {

    var tappedCount: Int = 0 {
        didSet { 
            label.text = "\(tappedCount)"
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let pageController = PageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
        // this will trigger the `didSet` from PageViewController, resulting
        // in the callback being propagated downstream
        pageController.buttonCallback = { self.tappedCount += 1 }
    }
}
```